# Nest-JS getting 404 not found error when return string

Tags: nestjs

I have boards controller and i made function like this.

```
@Get('/pay')
  pay(): string {
    return 'asdasdasd';
  }
```

then i checked on terminal and
[Nest] 9076  - 2022. 02. 12. 오후 4:13:12     LOG [RoutesResolver] BoardsController {/boards}: +10ms
[Nest] 9076  - 2022. 02. 12. 오후 4:13:12     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/boards/pay, GET} route +1ms
my router mapped well.
so i typed url like this
-> localhost:3000/boards/pay

but if i go that url,
only {"statusCode":404,"message":"can not find pay","error":"Not Found"}
came out.

how can i solve it?

this is my project structure
[image]